# Android - Java - Get nth element in JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, object

My JSON file contains several attributes. One of them is a list of objects. I need to access this list via a numerical key, ie the 1st, the 2nd etc element.

When getting the `nth element` I want to access its attributes by a alphabetical key.

Example:

```
MyObj.get("itemlist").get(0).get("attribute")
```

If I do this I'm forced to convert the whole thing to an `JSONArray` from which (afaik) I can't access my attributes via a key but just by position.

Here's my JSON string:

```
{
"id": 1,
"items": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "video",
        "name": "test.mp4"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "image",
        "name": "pic.jpg"
    }
],
"name": "test"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: post json String also from which u want to access attribute

Comment: I don't understand why your `MyObj.get("itemlist").get(0).get("attribute")` wouldn't work..seems legit to me! You retrieve the itemlist (which is an array), get the 0th index (which is an object), then get the attribute from the object. What's wrong with this exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, don't quite understand why but when I do the following it works:

```
JSONArray MyList = new JSONObject(filePath).getJSONArray("items");
System.out.println((((JSONObject) MyList.get(1)).get("type")));
```

So I just omitted the MyObj and targeted the list directly.